# Why is image hard cropping for one image using add_image_size not working?

Tags: php, images

Why is hard cropping for the `blog-grid-even`size not working?

When uploading an original that is 667x596, the `blog-grid-odd` and `blog-grid-featured` sizes are correctly cropped from the left top edge. But the `blog-grid-even` size is resized from the original 667x596 size, not cropped.

I've tried this without using the `add_action(after_setup_theme...`, force regenerated thumbnails many times, deleted all images and started over, etc., with no luck. This is not a GD library issue; the other image sizes are being cropped.

I've tried `add_image_size( 'blog-grid-even', 323, 301, true);` and nothing changes for that size. I can change the crop parameters for the other sizes, and they change after I force regenerate thumbnails.

This is not an image display issue on the front end; the `blog-grid-even` image in /uploads/ is being resized,not cropped.

```
function wpse_setup_theme() {
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'blog-grid-odd', 323, 596,array( 'left', 'top' ) );
add_image_size( 'blog-grid-even', 323, 301, array( 'left', 'top' ) );
add_image_size( 'blog-grid-featured', 667, 347, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); 
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_setup_theme' );
```

Original:

[image]

667, 347:

[image]

323, 596

[image]

323, 301

[image]

Comment: Are you really sure it is not cropped? Note that the aspect ratio of 667x596 and 323x301 are very similar, both are close to 1.1. Try with a original image with a very different aspecto ratio and check it.

Comment: Interesting; that's correct. I tried with a larger image than 667x596 and one with a different ratio and WP did crop. So this is wierdness with WP, I guess. Rather than reallly cropping when aspect rations are close, it resizes the entire image.

Comment: I don't know the exact maths behind WordPress image manipulation, but I think it is not something weirdness. I just thinkg It is very difficult for a human eye to apreciate difference between aspect ratio of 1.11 (667x596) and 1.07 (323x301).

Comment: But I asking WP to hard crop left and top, and it doesn't; it resizes the entire image. Added the images above.

Comment: I fully understand what you mean, but It is the expected behaviour. First, image is resized to the specified dimensions until either width or height is met; then it is cropped. Note how all images are first resized and then cropped, but 667x347 and 323x596 versions already have the specified width or height because it is the same than the original, so they are just cropped.

Comment: You're right; thanks! Add your comments as an answer and I can accept it.